# Appending select character of a string to list

Tags: python, string, list, char, append

With the string `ABCDEFGHIJKLM` I am trying to achieve the following:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLM
0123456789012
```

The first `if` statement works, but the `else` statement breaks with:

> `position.append(str(x[1]))`
>   TypeError: `'int'` object is not subscriptable

This is the code:

```
number = []
count = 0
for x in range(string):
    if count <= 9:
        number.append(str(x))
    else:
        number.append(str(x[1]))
    count = count+1
number = ''.join(map(str, number))
print(number)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: In addition, the first character of a string(or any indexable object in python) should be `str(x)[0]`, not `str(x)[1])`.

Comment: @M.T I think the OP wants the second char.

Comment: it should be str(x)[-1]. So u get the last char. so that it works with more than 2 digits number

Comment: Thanks all, Idos' answer fixed my syntax oversight. julivico, excellent alternative. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this *hack*: `int(str(s)[1])` Or `(str(s)[1])` depending on your wishes:

```
>>> s = 12
>>> int(str(s)[1])
2
>>> (str(s)[1])
'2'
```

Answer (score 1):

By performing the operation

```
str(x[1])
```

You're trying to perform a substring on the integer x, and *then* convert it to a string.

A string is a container of characters, and the substring function allows us to retrieve one or more characters from this set.

An integer is not a container of other objects and therefore is not classed as a subscriptable object (it does not implement the `__getitem__()` method). We cannot retrieve specific characters from it.

The solution is to reverse your operation order - convert the integer to a string *first*, and then perform a substring on it to retrieve the second character.

```
str(x)[1]
```

We can improve this by making it take the last character only, which would accomodate for numbers greater than 99:

```
str(x)[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it like this and get rid of the `if else` statement... and would work for strings of any lenght.

`number = []
for x in range(string):
    number.append(str(x % 10))
number = ''.join(map(str, number))
print(number)`